# How to distinguish two UITableView having a same custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi I have two UITableView in a UIView class and are loaded with same custom UITableViewCell. Custom tableview cell contains a UITextField. That means the two UITableView contains a UITextfield of same custom cell. When I select any of that textfield, how do I know which tableView's textfield is selected? Please help me..

Comment: You can use tag for identify cell uniquely.

Comment: yes it's work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITextField *txt = ----;
```

`txt.superView.superview` will give you the required `UITableView` instance.
To be more clear :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = txt.superView;   // In your case custom cell
UITableView *yourTable = cell.superView;
```

Comment: And it will break as soon as they change the view hierarchy.

Comment: @Desdenova : Firstly, this wasn't the scope of question. Secondly, please explain your point.